# Filemaker and Quickbook Connectivity

Tags: quickbooks, filemaker

Is there a way to push data to quick books from filemaker without using the plugin FM Books connector? I would like to avoid paying the licensing fee for the plugin. Could I export the data our as xml to quickbooks or use the ODBC\JDBC plugin?

Comment: I know nothing about Quickbooks. You can certainly export as XML from Filemaker, and use a custom XSLT stylesheet to transform the result to Quickbooks XML schema (assuming there is such a thing and you know what it looks like) during the export.

Comment: yea, it's called QBXML, but I've read it's really buggy when dealing with it from filemaker

Comment: @michael.hor257k This is a statement I've read about XMLQB, not XML, and I haven't actually tested it for myself, just read about it. I'm still researching how to approach the problem, so once I start actually writing the xml, I'll let you know how buggy it is. I threw the comment out there to see if you've had a similar experience with QBXML

Answer (score 0):

One very good option would be to check out Geist Interactive's recently introduced [fmQBO](https://www.geistinteractive.com/filemaker-quickbooks-online-connector/) product.